# Suggesting options in select menu for better user interface

Tags: javascript, xml, algorithm, database-management

I recently developed a search which will gather prices from three online shops and compare them to provide the user with the best choice available to them.Its been hosted [here](http://buyhatke.com/search.php)

However, I want it to make as suggestive as the search on [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/)

So, i wanna know, how can they come up with the options as soon as you type. Do, they store the data in some XML file or do they make call to database.

I just wish to know the efficient way to do this, given i have list of items.

Thanks :)

Comment: They probably load it from a database into memory on the server in a format that can be accessed quickly, and then make ajax calls from the page while you type. Check this out - http://nowjs.com/examples/autocomplete also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess in the front-end of the Flipkart's site ,they may use a jquery plugins to show the suggestions (such as [jquery.autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/));in the server side, you can store the data in the cache, and transfer them to the front-end as [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format

Comment: Can you please illustrate how to store data in cache, any link ??